# Certificate use on azure-active-directory proxy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a solution / security requirements from our customer:
1.  Multi-Factor Authentication: Users digital identities will be established by authenticating users using their assigned username, password and an approved Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) method.
2.  Conditional Access to restrict connectivity from Home PCs, etc: 
a.  For users on new devices: Access will be restricted to authorised devices. Authorised devices will be verified using a device certificates (sometimes referred to as a client certificate) issued by the customer’s Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) service when a device is first enrolled.
b.  For users on older devices: Access will be restricted by an IP address range.

We have prototyped the use of an Azure Application Proxy (to meet Requirement #1 for MFA above). However, through testing we’ve found that we can’t get the certificates to work via the proxy.

Installed the Cert on the JBOSS app server sitting behind the AAD PRoxy. This then gets blocked by the proxy.

I would like to register the Cert (or multiple certs) on the proxy, to allow secure access from the client devices to the Azure platform (App Servers / Proxy or gateway) .

There is no option in the Azure AAD to install a cert.